# Redirect still remains in the same page in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to redirect to my home page, but this doesn't work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logout(HttpSession session) {
    this.setSessionAccount(session, null);
    return this.getRedirect("/index");
}
```

My current page is `host/u/center`. There's some response record:

[image]

Comment: How about posting the relevant code which would be the getRedirect("") method???????

Answer (score 0):

You should

```
return "redirect:/index"
```

instead of calling another method of the controller.

Comment: The method just return "redirect:" + action;The return value equals "redirect:/index"

Comment: Then you should post more details about your question.

Comment: My current page is http://localhost:8080/weixin/u/center(user center), I want to logout.So, I request http://localhost:8080/weixin/u/logout by get method.In the controller i redirect to the "/index",but it still remains in u/center.

Answer (score 0):

I know what's the problem.
I use an ajax get request.
So I still remains in the same page.
Anyway,tanks for your answers.